# External share in android

Tags: android, share, external

I want to receive the externally shared content from others apps to my android app.

I have checked this url https://developer.android.com/training/sharing/receive.html?hl=es and handled the receiving intent in my activity.

I have also implemented the external share of content from my application to other apps installed in the phone.

I am getting the below issues in receiving the content from other apps to my android app.

1. When I share any photo from Facebook app to my application, it each time open a new app with the activity which I have mentioned in the manifest with **intent-filters**
2. But when I share any content from Facebook to my app, a activity open ups with in my app only. It does not open up a new Facebook app.

I also want to implement this in my app, so that if users of my app will share any content from others apps to my app, it will not open a new app but should open the the activity within that app only.

Please help me if anyone have idea here.

Thanks a lot.

Comment: try the github example code... https://github.com/gorbin/ASNE

Comment: Did you looked at "singleTop" activity's launchMode? https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/activity-element.html#lmode